# Xamarin on Visual Studio dnt show tips

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

When I'm programming in VB, when I type "msgbox(" (example), the interface presents me help/tips, like the data I have to insert after any comma. And info about the structure of this function.
Now I'm using Xamarin in VS and this help/tip does not appear.
Is there a way to enable this feature or do not have this support?
Thx.

VS 2015

Answer (score 0):

There are a great tool for visual studio.
-> Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2015

Installing this tool you will get a lot of functions.

Its free and the download is very fast.

Read more about and get the link to download: 
[Productivity Power Tools](http://www.macoratti.net/16/06/vs_pptools1.htm)